# Why 404.html page is not shown

Tags: .htaccess

I have this .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On

ErrorDocument 404 /404.html

RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^$ index\.html

RewriteRule ^(.+)\.html$ index.php?page=$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^robots.txt$ /generator.php?what=robots [L]

RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ /generator.php?what=sitemap [L]
```

If I go at: site.com/blablalblabla
I get 404 NOT FOUND, but it doens't show my 404.html page. Why?

Thank you

Comment: What 404 message are you getting exactly, the web server's or the browser's? As far as I understand your rules, an invalid request will always go to index.php, won't it?

Comment: To determine Pekka's question, use the following command on Mac or Linux: `wget -S --spider site.com/blablalblabla`. Please post the update.

Comment: unfortunately..... the browser! Yes... I would like to send the request to index.php

Comment: HTTP request sent, awaiting response...
  HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
  Date: Wed, 16 Feb 2011 14:27:49 GMT
  Server: Apache/2.2.9 (Debian) PHP/5.2.6-1+lenny8 with Suhosin-Patch mod_ssl/2.2.9 OpenSSL/0.9.8g
  X-Powered-By: PHP/5.2.6-1+lenny8
  Content-Length: 2
  Keep-Alive: timeout=15, max=100
  Connection: Keep-Alive
  Content-Type: text/html
Remote file does not exist -- broken link!!!

Debian-40-etch-64-LAMP:~#

Comment: @Damiano okay. But that sounds like your mod_rewrite rules don't work in the first place?

Comment: @Pekka exactly! very strange...because if i write: site.com/pagename.html "pagename" is on $1 variable... so it works but 404 not :/

Answer (score 0):

IMHO if the server fires up a 404, the 404.html will be the new REQUEST_URI to transform. The new uri will also go over all the rewrite rules and ending up redirected to index.php?page=404.

Try do add this rule condition:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^\/404\.html$
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.html$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try making a 404.md file with the following inside:

```
---
permalink: <insert 404 file path here>
---
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).